# React-parent component is taking input children's value 1 character missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created an Input component like this:

```
  import React, { useState } from 'react'
  const Input = ({ name, placeholder, type, className, inputRef, defaultValue, preventDefaultBehavior, style, timeout = 2000,
        onChange, onDoubleClick, onFocus, onBlur }) => {        
        const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);
        const [typingTimeout, setTypingTimeout] = useState(0);        
        function handleChange(e) {
            if (typingTimeout)
                clearTimeout(typingTimeout);
            setValue(e.target.value);
            if (onChange) {
                setTypingTimeout(
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        onChange({ target: { name, value } });
                    }, timeout)
                );
            }
        };
        function handleKeyPress(e) {
            if (e.keyCode !== 13 || timeout <= 1000)
                return;
            if (typingTimeout)
                clearTimeout(typingTimeout);        
            onChange({ target: { name, value } });
        }
        return (
            <input
                name={name}
                className={className}
                type={type}
                ref={inputRef}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                style={style}
                value={value}
                onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
                onChange={handleChange}
                onDoubleClick={onDoubleClick}
                onMouseDown={preventDefaultBehavior}
                onBlur={onBlur}
                onFocus={onFocus}
            />
        );
    };
    export default Input;
```

I'm using that Input component on the parent like this:

```
const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
<Input onChange={e => setUrl(e.target.value)} name="url" 
  placeholder="URL" type="text" defaultValue={url} />
```

However, parent component is not taking the last character of the input, such as:

input: 'abc'

parent state: 'ab'

> I tried `useEffect` and `async/await` but it didn't work for me.

Comment: There is something wrong in onHandleKeyPress event. You are timing out at every moment this has created some issue. You can debug step by step

Comment: I would store the value in a constant and then use it in timeout onChange({ target: { name, value } }) part. That should work. Something like this:
`function handleChange(e) {
    if (typingTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(typingTimeout);
    }

    const val = e.target.value;

    setValue(_val);
    if (onChange) {
      setTypingTimeout(
        setTimeout(function () {
          onChange({ target: { name, value: val } });
        }, timeout)
      );
    }
  }`

Comment: It worked thanks mihajlo !